# Deleting Records in multiple tables of dynamo db asynchronously

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I implemeted a code that deletes multiple records in a table and when that deletion is completed then goes to another table to delete it's record. But the thing is I am not deleting all records of a table just making query to some of the records that have range key (id = '1423') and all records related to this key I get and using foreach loop I then delete the records. Same I am doing in other table as well.

KeyPoints about my code : In both table "id" is not the primary key and also in both Table A and Table B I have this same "id" = 1423.

Code snippet :

```
    data: function(tableName, id){
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     var scanParams = {
      TableName: tableName,
      KeyConditionExpression: "#getId = :p",
      ExpressionAttributeNames:{
       "#getId": "id"
      },
      FilterExpression: '#getId = :v1' ,
      ExpressionAttributeValues:{
       ":v1" : id
      }
     };  
    AWS.docClient.scan(scanParams, function(err, data) {
     if (!_.isNil(err)) {
      console.error("Error :", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      reject(err)
     } else {
        if(_.size(data.Items) > 0){
          data.Items.forEach(function(obj, i){
          var params = {
            TableName: scanParams.TableName,
            Key: {"hashKey":obj[hashKey]},
            ReturnValues: 'NONE', // optional (NONE | ALL_OLD)
            ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'NONE', // optional (NONE | TOTAL | INDEXES)
            ReturnItemCollectionMetrics: 'NONE', // optional (NONE | SIZE)
          }
          AWS.docClient.delete(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
              console.error("Unable to delete items :", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
              reject(err)
            } else {
                console.log('Deleted the records in the table')
                resolve('success')
              }// successful response
          });
        })
      } else {
          console.log('No record in table')
          resolve('success')
        }
      }
    })
  })
 }
```

I am calling this data function in other two files just passing different table name in the parameters, i.e., here : function(tableName, id) and id is same. Also wanted to know that are there any loopholes in asynchronous way and is it better than synchronous method that I am using. Any performance issue or operation cost.

Answer (score 0):

--> My problem solved by using filter expression and scan all items with the id and then using for loop and deleting them.